# Priority Queues & Persistence

Tags: java, data-structures, persistence, message-queue, priority-queue

I have a Java system that receives messages over the network in a proprietary binary format which it needs to decode, process and do something with. The messages have an implied priority depending on their payload. I'd like to use the semantics of a priority-queue in the system with separate consumer threads reading the queue. The problem, is that once the system has accepted a message over the network, it must guarantee to handle it eventually, even if the system went down between receipt and processing. As such I'd like to back my priority-queue with persistence. I'm looking for light-weight ways to achieve this in Java inside a web container process as against using a fully blown ESB or similar.

Some additional info: we are in the Amazon cloud and JMS is not an option in our environment unfortunately. We could use SQS, but this doesn't support a priority concept and requires polling which is not really ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly is JMS not an option? It sounds like that's exactly what you need.

Comment: JMS just requires a JAR and some disk space. e.g. ActiveMQ.  If its the disk space that's out of the question, you are going to have a problem with persistence.

Comment: Running a brokered JMS with cross zone fail over is not something my operations team have experience of. Just a jar+disk space completely ignores operational issues.

Answer (score 0):

SQS uses long polling, so it adds very low overhead and practically no latency. For priorities you can use multiple queues. One for each priority.